# Data Vault apps with Unlock Pattern

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, security, password

I'm currently using the Wallet app to keep my bank acct#s, CC#s etc. safely on my phone. However, entering the password when I need to unlock the codes is kind of an annoyance. Specially when you wanna look up a number to fill up a form.

So, I'm looking for an alternative that uses unlock patterns instead. I know the pattern is potentially less secure than the password but, it's something I can live with :)

What are the alternatives available?

Comment: There is a bit of an issue there. The app should use some form of encryption like `blowfish` or `AES`. Your password acts as the key to this, so an unlock pattern may not generate even close to the uniqueness needed and would never be considered

Comment: Good point. I would think that if you enforce a minimum 4point unlock pattern that there's still sufficient room to build a secure key from it. BUT.. I guess no program manager would be open to build a sensitive data app with dumbed down security :)

Comment: Yes you could from 4 points, but you would also be able to figure out how the generated it from 4 points, the amount of possible codes would be something like 5! a really really low number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a combination of keepassdroid, wavelauncher and clipstore, which allows me to access my password manager from any app without having to close it, and copy my password to the clipstore before returning to the app I was in. Sounds more complicated than it is!

Alternatively, many like lastpass for automatic password storage and entry.

But if you really want something gesture based, maybe biowallet along with it's separate biowallet browser might be of insterest. You can assign a signature, which is infinitely more secure than point to point gestures.